# Running different java programs parallely on different machines in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Here is my requirement, could any one please let me know what java technology i can use for the same:

"A java program runs on a machine say A and it asks for ip address of machines say 3 machines. On giving the ip addresses as command line arguments, this program will send 3 modules(java programs performing some operations) to these machines of which we have provided ip addresses. Now these programs will execute on those machine and their result will be send back to the machine A where we are running our main program. Here i can combine the results of executed modules on different machine. That's it."

But after spending a lot of time on Google i could not able to find any specific framework/technology for this. So i thought of this forum.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than a _forum_ this is a Q&A site. =)

Comment: No question is bad question if it can be answered and my questioned has been answered two persons. You can find below the answer if you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the requirements imply different machines (nodes), it should be a *distributed* solution   not just *parallel*.

***Parallel***:
You can easily achieve parallelism using [the concurrent facilities provided by the Java's standard API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

***Distributed***: If your requirements don't fit [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), you might consider implementing your custom solution using messaging either *JMS*,e.g., [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/), or *Advanced Message Queuing Protocol* e.g.,[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework very similar to this called [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Comment: thanks for your reply.. it helped in achieving my task.